# Use of unassigned local variable in an if-else statement that assigns it

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-errors

I have the following code that parses some strings into doubles

```
double number;
double exponent;
if(!double.TryParse(line1, out number) &&
   !double.TryParse(line2, out exponent))
   throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
else
   number *= 10.0 * exponent;
```

I'm getting an error with the compiler that the `exponent` is being used when it's not assigned (Use of unassigned local variable 'exponent'). However, I do not get the error with the `number` variable even though it's being treated in the same manner. Additionally, the `&&` coupled with the `out` specifier in the functions being called in the if statement pretty much should guarantee that both number and exponent are assigned by the time it reaches the else block.

The following code DOES compile.

```
double number;
double exponent;
if(!double.TryParse(line1, out number))
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
else{
    if(!double.TryParse(line2, out exponent)){
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
    }else{
        number *= 10.0 * exponent;
    }
}
```

Why is this the case? In the first code sample, aren't both variables guaranteed to be assigned by the time the else statement is executed? Aren't both code samples equivalent logically? Is this a limitation of the compiler? Actually, I'm kinda surprised the compiler is smart enough to recognize the case in the bottom code sample in the first place.

Comment: Why do you write && instead of || ?

Comment: In the second example, when are you declaring exponent?

Comment: doh! It was a stupid mistake I hadn't noticed! I can't believe I was stuck at this for a while....

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson I hand-wrote that code. I forgot to declare exponent. I edited my question to fix it.

Comment: Hey, at least it's solved. Be sure to accept the answer that helped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want `||` instead of `&&`. Currently, you're only throwing an exception if *both* lines are invalid - if the first line is valid, you're never even parsing the second. I assume you actually only want to use `number` and `exponent` if both of them are valid...

So your code should be (with more idiomatic formatting):

```
if (!double.TryParse(line1, out number) || !double.TryParse(line2, out exponent))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
}
else
{
    number *= 10.0 * exponent;
}
```

Or to make the whole thing easier to understand, reduce the number of negatives involved - show what you want to do if everything *is* valid, and handle the negative situations in the `else`:

```
if (double.TryParse(line1, out number) && double.TryParse(line2, out exponent))
{
    number *= 10.0 * exponent;
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
}
```

Comment: I am using &&.. but I see your point. This was a stupid mistake that I haven't noticed :/ Thanks!

Comment: @9a3eedi: Yes, that's my point - you're using `&&` but you shouldn't be.

Comment: @JonSkeet what I meant to say was the statement "I'm pretty sure you want `&&` instead of `||`" implies that I'm using `||` when I wasn't. I think you meant to say "I'm pretty sure you want `||` instead of `&&`" . ;)

Answer (score 3):

`&&` short circuits, so if the parsing of `number` fails the second `TryParse` will never execute and thus `exponent` could be left uninitialized.

Side note - you want to fail if *either* parse fails, so you really want OR (`|`) instead of AND (`&`)

Some options:

- change `&&` to `||` to fix the logic error
- Reverse the logic to put the "happy case" first:

  ```
  double number;
  double exponent;
  // you can use "&&" here because you don't reference exponent unless both parses succeed.
  if(double.TryParse(line1, out number) &&
     double.TryParse(line2, out exponent))
  {
     number *= 10.0 * exponent;
  }
  else
     throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string");
  ```

Comment: Changing `&&` to `&` would end up going to the "everything's fine" case when the OP doesn't really want to though, I suspect.

Comment: @JonSkeet True - I focused on the compiler error and missed the logic error.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, because in your top example, both number and exponent have to be null to get to a non-breakable path:

if(!double.TryParse(line1, out number) &&
   !double.TryParse(line2, out exponent))

this won't compile, either:

if(!double.TryParse(line1, out number) ||
   !double.TryParse(line2, out exponent))

Because if the line fails (isn't a number) then you bail out of the IF statement before you initialize exponent.  Your 2nd IF statement is the right way to do it.

Comment: Neither `number` nor `exponent` can be null

Comment: Exactly!  Which is why his logic wouldn't work...  If number is a valid number, the if terminates before it evaluates the 2nd number and sees if it can assign a value to exponent.